# multiple spinner android depend on each other

Tags: android, android-spinner

i have 3 spinners, first spinner is `txt_kategori` ;
second `txt_kondisi` ;
third `txt_penanganan` ; the second depends on the first and the third depends on the second input, here is my code

```
txt_kategori.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, condition[position]);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
            txt_kondisi.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    txt_kondisi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, handling[position]);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
            txt_penanganan.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

the problem is `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.View.getContext()' on a null object reference`
at `ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, handling[position]);`

Comment: Try `ActivityName.this` instead of `view.getContext()`

Comment: @SathishKumarJ yes that's right

Comment: @Surya you can vote my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ActivityName.this` instead   `view.getContext()`

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, condition[position]);
```

change to

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ActivityName.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, condition[position]);
```